# Any way to compare activity between Meta and the normal sites?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, analytics

Is there any statistics about how many page views has the Meta subsection compared to the normal site?

Comment: In terms of homepage views? Or on each page?

Comment: Are you talking about MSO or normal per-site metas?  Because of the special nature of MSO, it would have much different results than the other meta sites?  Are by "page views"  are you looking at average per post?  Or just overall page views of any page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the amount of people using meta and main from [quantcast's reports](https://www.quantcast.com/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc/traffic/sites). Just expand the sites you want to see. For average views per question and overall question views, http://data.stackexchange.com will probably suit your needs.

Comment: It seems that only 1 of 170 people from SO goes to meta

Comment: @Sam note that some people on MSO don't visit SO at all, but come from other SE sites for the questions that apply for the whole network.

Comment: you mean that people on meta are less than 1/170 of the people on the total SE community? If it's like that then meta may not be very representative of the whole community.. Why people don't use it?

Comment: @Sam less than 1/170 of the Stack **Overflow** community. About one in 205 from the whole Stack **Exchange** network visit MSO.

Comment: I'm wondering if the statistics are calculated on the page views, on the unique logged users per day or on the unique logged users per month?